# Flash ActionScript 3 Sequential swf uploader issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, load

I wanted to create swf file that will load all the other 1.swf , 2.swf , 3 , 4 and so on sequentially and then loop to the first one again.

**THE PROBLEM**: this is the output "ready to call eFrame
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at main_fla::MainTimeline/eFrame()"

This is what Ive got (BTW Its not my code:) THE PROBLEM is IN this part of the code

> mcExternal= loader.content as MovieClip;
>   var current:int=mcExternal.currentFrame;
>   var total:int=mcExternal.totalFrames;

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var rq:URLRequest;
var loader:Loader= new Loader();
stage.addChild(loader);

var numOfMovies:int = 3;
var path:String = "mov/";
var myMovies:Array=["1.swf","2.swf", "3.swf"];
var movieNum:int=1;
var mcExternal:MovieClip;

/*Load Req*/
function loadSWF():void {
    var tPath:String = path + movieNum;
    rq=new URLRequest(tPath + ".swf");
    loader.load(rq);

    // waiting for the loader to be ready
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onComplet);

}
/*Load Req*/


function onComplet(e:Event):void {
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onComplet);
    trace("ready to call eFrame");
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
}


function eFrame(e:Event):void {
    mcExternal= loader.content as MovieClip;
    var current:int=mcExternal.currentFrame;
    var total:int=mcExternal.totalFrames;

    /*trace(current);
    trace(total);*/

    if (current >= total) {
        trace("Load next swf ");
        loader.unloadAndStop();

        mcExternal=null;
        movieNum++;
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
        rq=null;
        loadSWF();

        if (movieNum>=numOfMovies) {
            movieNum=0;
        }
    }
}


loadSWF();
```

Comment: can you do trace(stage); ?

Comment: I am able to run your code as is with no issue. What version of the Flash IDE are you running? I'm using CS6.

Comment: trace(stage); gives me [object Stage] in output

Comment: I always get a multiple TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at main_fla::MainTimeline/eFrame()

Comment: It seams that the movieclip I made is referencing to null but it should reference loader.content in order to get totalframes and currentFrame methods

Comment: Ohh I got IT I was using action script 2 in the loaded content which instead of MovieClip returned DisplayObject thats why I always got null!!!!!

Comment: CAN you please help me to convert loader.content that holds swf made in as2 to MovieClip So that I can get Totalframes method